# Highcharts - detect when render (or redraw) event is caused by a resize/reflow?

Tags: events, highcharts

I am drawing some custom SVG elements over columns in a column chart.

I need to redraw them if the chart redraws because of a window resize, so that they maintain correct position and size over the columns.

I have a `chart.events.render` event handler, but the `render` event doesn't tell you *why* it re-rendered, and I know that sometimes my `render` event handler fires because I also trigger redraws from code for certain things.

I checked the `redraw` event also, and it's type is always `"redraw"` no matter what is triggering the redraw.

Is there any way to detect when a redraw/re-render is happening *specifically* because of a resize/reflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `reflow` method and call your alignment function after the process.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'reflow', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        console.log('after reflow');
    });
})(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kc1zdg28/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  I don't actually redraw my stuff when `reflow` fires, since from that `console.log()` that seems to happen a _lot_, but I do use it to set a flag indicating that a reflow did happen, and then the next time `render` fires, if the flag is set, I then do the realignment.